# How to leverage browser cache using .htaccess on nginx?

Tags: htaccess, apache, nginx

I'm trying to increase the pagespeed of our website [ubercore.co](http://ubercore.co). I'm using [PageSpeed Insights for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/using_chrome)  extension to analyze the pagespeed. It has suggested me to "Leverage browser cache". This is where I'm stuck.

I've tried some modifications to .htaccess file like this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

and get nothing.

Later did some research and found that .htaccess is only for Apache server. Correct me if I'm wrong.

But, when I see the header response of our webpage found that the server is nginx. Then why my host has the .htaccess file in web root? I'm confused.

What I need in short:
How to cache static contents for [this](http://ubercore.co) site?

Useful links:
[Nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess)

**Update 1:**

Here is a screenshot of what I have, server is nginx:
[image: Respnonse headers]

My question is simple, **I need to cache all static content given the environment.**

**Update 2:**
As suggested by [dan](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/28389/dan) found that the server is indeed Apache not nginx. I don't really understand it but let it be it's off topic.

Now my problem:

Server software : **Apache/2.4.7 (Unix)**

Need : **.htaccess code to set browser cache expiry time.**

Comment: You should first confirm if your web host is using nginx to serve your site, or as a proxy, and if the former, then ask how you might cache content specific to nginx, which would not use a .htaccess file.

Comment: @dan The server is nginx. But my host is a shared server and he had an .htaccess file in web root by default. I've updated the question with screenshots for you.

Comment: Although the header may indicate it's being served with nginx, it could be served through a proxy as well. For example, if your hosting company uses a CDN, the header might indicate ngninx when it's served through Apache. You should confirm that your site is being served with nginx, and not proxied through a CDN. If that's the case, then you should edit the question to remove all .htaccess reference in your title and question since that's not relevant. Lastly, your final sentence is not really a question at all.

Comment: @dan Thanks for the quick response dan. If the server happens to be Apache then why my .htaccess code is not working. Btw, the non-www to www rewrite rule is working fine.

Comment: Again, please confirm your server, and then edit your question to be specific to that and it will be reviewed to be reopened.

Comment: @dan Thanks for your advice. Learned few important concepts I've been unaware of till now.

Comment: Vote to reopen. It is clear what is being asked currently. I can also provide an answer.

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko: reopened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your cache expiry in the vhost configuration on Nginx server, for example:-

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires 1y;
}
```

You'll only be able to use `location` in a server block however (and not `http` block) but you could insert this into a separate file and then include it in each `server` block that requires this though.

[Read up on leverage browser caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?csw=1#LeverageBrowserCaching) at Google.